# Android JSON Parsing not working

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-listview, getjson

I'm using [Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) tutorials to get data from a JSON file and view it as a list or grid. But when run this application, the app crashes and exits. I couldn't find any error on the  code. You can download the source code from above tutorial link. However I provided the class files here. Please someone help me to solve the problem as soon as possible. Thanks in advanced.

AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java

```
package com.example.samplejsonparsing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });



    }

}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.samplejsonparsing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

SingleMenuItemActivity.java

```
package com.example.samplejsonparsing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

    // JSON node keys
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        String cost = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
        String description = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
        TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

        lblName.setText(name);
        lblCost.setText(cost);
        lblDesc.setText(description);
    }
}
```

Maybe It can be a silly question but please don't ignore this.

```
08-08 10:18:50.240: D/AbsListView(14239): Get MotionRecognitionManager
08-08 10:18:50.285: D/AndroidRuntime(14239): Shutting down VM
08-08 10:18:50.285: W/dalvikvm(14239): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ee32a0)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.samplejsonparsing/com.example.samplejsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at com.example.samplejsonparsing.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at com.example.samplejsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:54)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239):    ... 11 more
08-08 10:19:39.280: I/Process(14239): Sending signal. PID: 14239 SIG: 9
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.samplejsonparsing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.samplejsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.example.samplejsonparsing.SingleMenuItemActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the exact error along with Logcat output from crash.

Comment: Some kind of "offtop" but I would recommend you to use gson library from Google to parse json. The code will be smaller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the project and compiled on my system. Its working fine. Please check your Manifest.xml if you have added the "INTERNET" permission. Please do add your Logcat output here so that one can understand what is the error.

Comment: See in your 5th line of the logcat :

08-08 10:18:50.295: E/AndroidRuntime(14239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.samplejsonparsing/com.example.samplejsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException



It states that the Network connection for getting the JSON from the URL is being performed on the main UI process thread. In the latest version of Android 4.0 and above, the Network Thread has to run in background thread using an Async Task or the app would crash.

Comment: You can use the two links to understand the Async Task :

[link 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)    
,
[link 2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: @Kabelash : if the solution helped you, then please accept the answer. I really need to increase my repo.